# Convert a list of tuples to multiple lists

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a way to parse some JSON into something usable.
I'm getting what's basically a list of X-tuple, for example with three values :

```
[
  [1, 323, 985],
  [98, 21234, 46135]
]
```

Now I'd like to parse that JSON and convert it to a list of lists. I'm okay with the type being always the same, so I think Float or Double would be the ideal since it should allow to hold any numerical value. Something like [[Float]] would be perfect. In this example that would be :

```
[[1.0, 98.0], [323.0, 21234.0], [985.0, 46135.0]]
```

This would be easy enough if I knew how many values would be in the document, but I don't, I only know they'll be number (either Int or Float). Is there a way to iterate over the fields of a tuple like you'd map over a list ? I realise that's not what a tuple is supposed to be for, but I have no control over what generates the json, and I'd really like to avoid writing by hand functions for 2-tuples, 3-tuples, 4-tuples ..

Thanks

EDIT : Seems like I'm looking for a generic version of unzip, that would work on any size

Comment: you are looking for `zip`

Comment: The examples you posted are both lists of lists, not lists of tuples..

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me if this question relates to a larger work with parsing JSON, but just in case: are you aware of [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson)?

Comment: Looks to me like I'm looking for the opposite of zip actually. As for the lists of lists, the first one is the json I have to parse, the second is the result I'm looking for. My problem being that I don't know how many values each lists will contain on the json side. I know of Aeson but I basically know only how to define simple data with it, not how to parse this without having to define a different data type for each possible number of Floats

Comment: This looks like a `transpose`.

Comment: It does look like what I'm looking for. I'm going to try it, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the JSON with the [`aeson`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.2.0) package using [`decode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:decode), and then flip the rows and columns of the 2D list with [`transpose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose).

```
import Data.Aeson (decode)
import Data.String (fromString)
import Data.List (transpose)

parseFloats :: String -> Maybe [[Float]]
parseFloats = fmap transpose . decode . fromString
```